# Snap to grid the dragged element with Google closure library

Tags: closures, draggable, google-closure-library

Please,

how to make in Google Closure Library draggable element and snap to grid?

Example: jQueryUI has option grid:

`$(".selector").draggable({grid: [50, 20]});`

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this in my project, so posting the solution (although I am sure there are many). My approach was to inherit the goog.fx.Dragger class and extend:

- constructor for supporting the grid parameters
- default action for doing the actual snapping

The code follows:

```
SnapDragger = function(target, grid, opt_handle, opt_limits) {
  goog.base(this, target, opt_handle, opt_limits);
  this.grid = grid;
}
goog.inherits(SnapDragger, goog.fx.Dragger);

SnapDragger.prototype.defaultAction = function(x, y) {
  x = Math.round(x / this.grid.x) * this.grid.x;
  y = Math.round(y / this.grid.y) * this.grid.y;
  goog.base(this, 'defaultAction', x, y);
}
```

You would then use the SnapDragger the same way as goog.ui.Dragger

```
var dragger = new SnapDragger(element, {x: 20, y: 50});
```